Page to update data that has Filepond with a database image, but does not send anything
I have a page to update the MySQL database registration, it is a Blog, because if the user types something wrong or adds a wrong photo, they can use this page to bring the completed data, as well as the image that was previously sent as standard on Filepond.
So when the user opens this page it comes with all the information filled in, including the image field using Filepond.
This way, once the user wants to add new images, as there are multiple images, they can do so.
For example, the user can add up to 4 images, but I can only send one. Later I can update the data and send one more, leaving the one that is already there.
So, if I have a default image, which came from the database, and I want to add 1 more, this default image cannot be sent. When creating a message, it brings the blob information, I will give an example below:
HTML
<div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label fs-14 text-dark" for="Imagem">Imagem</label><span class="font-size__0-85rem font-weight__900 text-danger"><sup><i class="ti ti-asterisk"></i></sup></span>
    <div class="filepond--div"><input type="file" class="multiple-filepond" id="Imagem[]" name="Imagem[]" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/webp" data-allow-reorder="true" data-max-files="4" data-max-file-size="3MB" multiple></div>
</div>

SCRIPT
/*-- ** - - FILEPOND - - ** --*/
const Str__Filepond_Multiple = document.querySelector('.multiple-filepond');
const Str__Filepond = FilePond.create(Str__Filepond_Multiple,{
    instantUpload: false,
    "server": {
        "load": "../Image/Blog/Upload/1920x1080/",
    },
    "files": [
        {
            "source": "<?php echo $qRecord["Image_1"]; ?>",
            "options": {"type":"local"}
        },
        {
            "source": "<?php echo $qRecord["Image_2"]; ?>",
            "options": {"type":"local"}
        },
        {
            "source": "<?php echo $qRecord["Image_3"]; ?>",
            "options": {"type":"local"}
        },
        {
            "source": "<?php echo $qRecord["Image_4"]; ?>",
            "options": {"type":"local"}
        }
    ],
    labelButtonAbortItemLoad: "Abortar…",
    labelButtonAbortItemProcessing: "Cancelar…",
    labelButtonProcessItem: "Enviar…",
    labelButtonRemoveItem: "Remover…",
    labelButtonRetryItemLoad: "Tentar novamente…",
    labelButtonRetryItemProcessing: "Tentar novamente…",
    labelButtonUndoItemProcessing: "Desfazer…",
    labelFileLoadError: "Erro durante carregamento…",
    labelFileLoading: "Carregando",
    labelFileProcessing: "Enviando",
    labelFileProcessingAborted: "Carregamento cancelado…",
    labelFileProcessingComplete: "Carregamento completo…",
    labelFileProcessingError: "Erro durante carregamento…",
    labelFileProcessingRevertError: "Erro durante reversão…",
    labelFileRemoveError: "Erro durante remoção…",
    labelFileSizeNotAvailable: "Tamanho não disponível…",
    labelFileWaitingForSize: "Aguardando tamanho…",
    labelIdle: "Arraste e solte sua imagem aqui ou <span class=\"filepond--label-action\">navegue</span>…",
    labelInvalidField: "O campo contém arquivos inválidos…",
    labelTapToCancel: "Toque para cancelar…",
    labelTapToRetry: "Toque para tentar novamente…",
    labelTapToUndo: "Toque para desfazer…",
    imageCropAspectRatio: 1,
    imageResizeMode: 'contain',
    imageResizeTargetWidth: 256,
    storeAsFile: true
});

Image that cames when I open the update Blog page:
Image 1
Inserted the new image, the I will send the form with the old and the new image:
Image 2
Page to update data that has Filepond with a database image, but does not send anything
Here we can see that the old image is the second one, the first one is the new (10.webp).
Then I puit a message error to check the result when I try to send:
Image 3
Here we have saying:

Erro (2): 2 images
1-10.webp: Image 1, recognized the image that I
put as a new one
2-blob: Image Old, that was in the database and I
want to maintain

The problem is exactly here. How do I add a new image, leaving the previous one if I want, using Filepond?
I tried everything but I couldn't, I read and re-read several topics, without success. I'm not experienced with JS.
